# Backup server permissions

Tags: permissions, ldap, backup, root

Currently I'm developing a control website for my home server. The server has LDAP setup for Mac's to login. The home directories are also on the server. I want to create a backup tool for my family, so they can backup while I'm off. I don't want to do this scheduled (at least not allways, since they must be able to start a backup right away).

I got stuck when I was trying to find a way to run the rsync commands as a privileged user.
I've got some ideas on this but I would like to hear the cons and pros of the options.

- Create simple **deamon** that runs as root and backup's folder -arg1 to -arg2 minding the old backup in -arg3.
- Run rsync as the logged in user by **remembering the users pass** at login at the control panel. (Problem: running ps will reveal password).
- Create special **rsync user** (Problem: rsync user can read **everything**).

The project is located at https://github.com/hermanbanken/ldap-control and this issue is also on GitHub at https://github.com/hermanbanken/ldap-control/issues/1.

Answer (score 1):

sudo is on OSX later versions.

sudo rsync .....

Comment: You do not get it. I know what rsync is and I don't want to run anything on the client (OSX) but on my server (Ubuntu) since that is where the users home folders live.